# How to put already defined vars and values into Python dict?

Tags: python, json, serialization, dictionary, python-requests

I have this code:

```
if 'instagramTV' in path:
    self.send_response(200)
    instaShortcode, LTV, EMAIL, TIME, userID, URL  = map(\
    qs.get, ['instaID', 'channelID', 'uEmail', 'Time', 'uID', 'contentUrl'])

    channelID, uEmail, instagramShortcode, uTime, uID, contentUrl = map(\
    lambda x : str(x)[2:-2], [LTV, EMAIL, instaShortcode, TIME, userID, URL])

    for i in (channelID, uEmail, instagramShortcode, uTime, uID, contentUrl):
        print i
    instaSTEP2 = requests.get("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/%s/"% instagramShortcode).json()
    instaMeID = instaSTEP2['media_id']
    instaINFO = requests.get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/%s?accesstoken=295391286.1b882b8.33fa51373fae4885b5c60ceb186e6560" % instaMeID).json()
    print instaINFO['data']['user']['profile_picture']
    print instaINFO['data']['user']['username']
    print instaINFO['data']['caption']['text']
    print instaINFO['data']['images']['standard_resolution']['url']
    ltvMSG = {'fromEMAIL': 'uEmail', 'toCHANNELID': 'channelID', 'timeSENT': 'uTime', 'profiePIC': "instaINFO['data']['user']['profile_picture']",'userNAME': "instaINFO['data']['user']['username']", 'msgBODY': "instaINFO['data']['caption']['text']", 'msgIMAGE': "instaINFO['data']['images']['standard_resolution']['url']"}
    print ltvMSG
```

First vars come in from a http get request, then I use some of those vars to make a api call, then I get back some json.

I'm trying to put some of the initial vars from the get request and some values from the api call into my own dict/json which eventually will go into a redis list.

print ltvMSG returns this:

```
{'userNAME': "instaINFO['data']['user']['username']", 'timeSENT': 'uTime', 'msgIMAGE': "instaINFO['data']['images']['standard_resolution']['url']", 'msgBODY': "instaINFO['data']['caption']['text']", 'fromEMAIL': 'uEmail', 'toCHANNELID': 'channelID', 'profilePIC': "instaINFO['data']['user']['profile_picture']"}
```

This is the structure I want but how do I make the real values appear as values to the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is adding those string literals to the dict. So if, instead of:

```
     loqootvMSG = {'fromEMAIL': 'uEmail', 'toCHANNELID': 'channelID', 'timeSENT': 'uTime', 'profilePIC': "instaINFO['data']['user']['profile_picture']",'userNAME': "instaINFO['data']['user']['username']", 'msgBODY': "instaINFO['data']['caption']['text']", 'msgIMAGE': "instaINFO['data']['images']['standard_resolution']['url']"}
```

You do:

```
     loqootvMSG = {'fromEMAIL': uEmail, 'toCHANNELID': channelID, 'timeSENT': uTime, 'profilePIC': instaINFO['data']['user']['profile_picture'],'userNAME': instaINFO['data']['user']['username'], 'msgBODY': instaINFO['data']['caption']['text'], 'msgIMAGE': instaINFO['data']['images']['standard_resolution']['url']}
```

It will store, for instance, the value of `uEmail`, not the string `'uEmail'`.

Comment: thank you. in your knowledge is there a more efficient manner to accomplish my goal? Point me in a direction that I may research. thanks again!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, so it's hard for me to help you accomplish it. I also don't really understand the data structures returned by the Instagram API, so I can't recommend a different way of using that data. For efficiency, it seems like the network overhead will be the bottleneck here, so I'm not sure you should really worry about the program's efficiency. It's probably more worth your time to think about the code's clarity. But, if something about the program is running slow, look at your data structures and operations and see where you can make changes.